# Is there a good graphical representation for the sampling distribution of relative risk?

Tags: relative-risk, sampling-distribution

For pedagogical reasons, I am interested in communicating graphically the sampling distribution of relative risks (histogram and CDF plot), specifically in the context of a matched-pair study design:

|  | Positive | Negative | Margin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Positive** | $a$ | $b$ | $a+b$ |
| **Negative** | $c$ | $d$ | $c+d$ |
| **Margin** | $a+c$ | $b+d$ | $n$ |

Suppose I have the estimated risk of positive in group 1 $= \widehat{r}_{1} = \frac{a+b}{n}$, and the estimated risk of positive in group 2 $ = \widehat{r}_{2} = \frac{a+c}{n}$, so that $\widehat{RR}_{1\text{ vs }2} = \frac{r_{1}}{r_{2}} = \frac{a+b}{a+c}$.

I know that $\ln\left(\widehat{RR}\right)$ is often described as having an approximately normal distribution, but is there a decent graphical representation of the sampling distribution of $\widehat{RR}$? (Under, say, the null hypothesis that $\widehat{RR}=1$)? Does that imply some exponential-normal distribution of $\widehat{RR}$?

Comment: You have a matched analysis in the table, but for convenience I think we can assume an unmatched analysis, correct? The general solution can be fixed up for the matched table if we begin with the classic example where $RR = a/(a+c) / (b/(b+d))$.

Comment: @AdamO If there is a difference between the matched and unmatched sampling dists, I would want to know about it, and would want to know both. :)